# Ant script to transfer multiple files using WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition (MQ FTE)

Tags: ant, ibm-mq

I have written an ant script to transfer a single file using IBM WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition.

```
<target name="filecopy">
   <fte:filecopy src="${src}" dst="${dst}" idproperty="id">
      <fte:filespec srcfilespec="${srcfile}" dstdir="${dstdir}"/>
   </fte:filecopy>
</target>
```

For two files, the script would look like below:

```
<target name="filecopy">
   <fte:filecopy src="${src}" dst="${dst}" idproperty="id">
      <fte:filespec srcfilespec="${srcfile1}" dstdir="${dstdir1}"/>
      <fte:filespec srcfilespec="${srcfile2}" dstdir="${dstdir2}"/>
   </fte:filecopy>
</target>
```

How can I modify the script so that it can support multiple files by accepting a string (e.g. a.txt,b.txt,c.txt) as parameter?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I modify the script so that it can support multiple files?

Since your example already sends multiple files, presumably you are asking how to transfer a *variable* number of files to be determined at run time.  There are a few options.

1. Use a wildcarded filespec.  All matching files will be transferred.
2. Transfer an entire directory recursively.
3. Dynamically generate the file transfer XML so as to include a filespec for each individual file.
4. Use a monitor that starts file transfers based on trigger criteria.

Based on the update, the requirement is to pass a string containing file names.  Most likely, you will want to use Option #3 above.  Pass the string of file names to something that can parse them, then generate the XML.  This can be done with shell scripting, or in Ant using something like [ant-contrib](/questions/tagged/ant-contrib), or many other ways.  There is nothing in the XSD for MQMFT that allows specification of file names natively as a delimited string.